# how to host blazor wasm on local iis during debug

Tags: .net, debugging, iis, blazor

i want to change IIS expres to local iis on my machine during development
did someone managed to do this ?
i installed IIS
i installed vstudio iis integration as needed in vs installer
i did created even for now simple 'localhost' website binded http on port lets say 49726

in vs project
i added new debug profile as FULL IIS - not expres. so it adds to launchSettings.json

```
   "IIS": {
  "commandName": "IIS",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "http://localhost:49726",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
},
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iis": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49726",
  "sslPort": 0
}
```

when i run this it asks me to run as admin
i do allow - it runs as admin
then it ask to me to allow change dest folder. i do allow. it changes to
`C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\BlazorAppIIS\BlazorAppIIS\Server`

then i see `403`. - i add IUSR user to allow to read/write into this folder. fine

then after refresh i see `403.14` - so it is Directory browsing is not enabled
when i do enable then i see FILEs / FOLDERS listed
but not actual application

what am i missing here? do i need to add some 'module' to IIS ? is the patch `C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\BlazorAppIIS\BlazorAppIIS\Server` correct? i known that it is not publish but im not publishing. i want to use it here in development time.

thanks and best regards !

Comment: You see FILEs / FOLDERS listed because you don't have a default document set, you can set a [default document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/defaultdocument/) for your website.

Answer (score 0):

`builder.WebHost.UseIISIntegration();`

solves this problem.
but i canot debug wasm - only api debug works. does any one knows why?
did someone used this feature at all ? :D
regards !